# Converting pdf to JSON

Tags: json, pdf, flexpaper

I need to convert pdf to json.I tried pdf2json https://github.com/flexpaper/pdf2json module to do that.its extracting only the text and creating JSON.But image datas are  not available in the JSON.Can anyone please suggest me how to get image information also in JSON.

Comment: Is there anything that people *won't* try to convert to JSON? What do you *actually* need to do with the PDF?

Comment: i want to render the pdf page as html with my own template

Comment: OK, cool. So what you need is to be able to access the PDF structure and content in your programming language of choice, and JSON [was just one possible means to that end](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), am I right? What programming language are you using?

Comment: im using node.js and python

Comment: In that case, searching for [node.js read pdf](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=node.js+read+pdf&t=ffsb&ia=qa) and [python read pdf](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+read+pdf&t=ffsb&ia=qa) would seem a good place to start. Both searches return various libraries, and comparisons of those libraries.